# Creating a Keybind using Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a keybind using the  button.

```
def LoginSQLEvent(event):
    print("In Keybinded Function")
    LoginSQL()

def LoginSQL():
    ...

LoginButton = tk.Button(Login, command=LoginSQL, text="Login", font=ButtonFont, bg=ScoutPurple, fg="white")
LoginButton.grid(row=4, column=3)
LoginButton.bind('<Return>',LoginSQLEvent)
```

Expected Results:
Login Function Executes on Return/Enter Key pressed
Actual Results:
Login Function Does Not Execute, No Error Code Produced When Return/Enter Key Pressed

Comment: You don't use bindings on buttons for something like this. The `command` argument is what you use. Change `command=LoginSQL` to `command=LoginSQLEvent` and get rid of the binding and the `event` argument in the function.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I want the button and the key to execute the function LoginSQL, the only reason that LoginSQLEvent exists is because the documentation told me to create it.

Comment: Then bind the return key to the frame not the button. Also you do not need both functions if you define `event=None`. this way both the button and return can call the same function.

Comment: @Mike-SMT `Login.bind('<Return>',LoginSQLEvent)` yields same results

Comment: You have not provided enough code to know what `Login` is. Is it a frame or a window?

Comment: Your binding will only work if your button has the keyboard focus. It probably doesn't if there are any other widgets on the screen.

Comment: @Mike-SMT: binding to the frame will likely yield the same results, since frames by default don't get keyboard focus.

Comment: @BryanOakley my assumption is everything is either on the root window or everything is in the same frame. I believe that if anything has focus inside of the frame the binding should work on the frame correct?

Comment: No there are multiple frames in the program. There are multiple widgets in each frame. I want the user to be able to press the Return key on the Login Frame, and the LoginSQL function be executed.

Comment: You will need to bind to the root window and then remove the bind when the login window is gone.

Comment: If the is an input field in the login page, it's better to add the bindings to the input fields since they will be the widgets that have focus.

Comment: Bryan makes a good point. In a login page there will be entry fields so you can bind to those and you will be able to activate the function with the return key. That would be better than binding to root and then removing the bind after login is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get both the button and the Enter/Return key to call the function we can change 2 things in your code.

First change `event` to `event=None`. By changing the argument to be defined by default as None you are able to call this function weather or not an argument is passed.

Next change the binding to be on the container of the button. The Login window in this case. (To be clear the focus needs to be in the same container as the button for the binding to work on a container that is not the root window)

```
import tkinter as tk


Login = tk.Tk()

def LoginSQL(event=None):
    print("Testing")

LoginButton = tk.Button(Login, command=LoginSQL, font=ButtonFont,
                        bg=ScoutPurple, text="Login", fg="white")
LoginButton.grid(row=4, column=3)

Login.bind('<Return>', LoginSQL)

Login.mainloop()
```